# Symfony Repository service configuration with multiple connections

Tags: symfony, doctrine, repository, yaml, connection

I have a Symfony app with two different database connections. Until yesterday I only needed the default connection but now I need the other one.

I configure my services in yaml and I have absolutely no idea what I have to do differently for the other connection to inject my repository.

The configuration looks like this:

```
services:
    somedata.repository:
        class: SomeBundle\Repository\SomedataRepository
        factory: ["@doctrine", getRepository]
        arguments:
            - SomeBundle:SomeEntity
```

Symfony throws the error:

> Unknown Entity namespace alias 'SomeBundle'.

What am I doing wrong?

edit:

Found the solution:

```
services:
    somedata.repository:
        class: SomeBundle\Repository\SomedataRepository
        factory: ["@doctrine.orm.{name_of_the_connection}_entity_manager", getRepository]
        arguments:
            - SomeBundle:SomeEntity
```

Comment: Maybe post your solution as answer instead. That will make it easier for people to see that the question is already answered.